# Android: how can I repeat image several times in drawable bitmap resource?

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, repeat

I have RelativeLayout and ImageView widget like this

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/ImgUp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:background="@drawable/piggy" />
```

and a drawable resource like this

```
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/sample" />
```

How can I repeat the same image a number of calculated repetition of times? (For example 4 times)

Answer (score 3):

Add `android:tileMode="repeat"` to your bitmap drawable resource. That will cause it to repeat on both axes until the view is filled. If you need an exact number of repeats, it would be better to do it as a custom view.

Comment: If I set android:tileMode="repeat", image will be reapet for all width but the last image will be truncated if there is not enough space to contain it.

Comment: For this reason, i have calculated the number of times that an image must be repeated, but i don't know how to continue.